# Determine if the language is $R$

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, reductions, undecidability

Consider the following language:

$$L = \{ \langle M \rangle \ |\ M \text { is a TM that decides the halting problem} \}$$

> determine whether or not the language is in $R$.

Now, from my understanding an $\langle M \rangle \in L$ doesn't necessarily returns the right answer but rather halts for every $\langle P, x \rangle$ where $p$ is a program (=TM) and $x$ is an input for the program.

I am guessing the language isn't decidable and can be showed as such by some reduction, but couldn't think of something useful.

I'll be glad for help.

Comment: Hint: what do you know of the halting problem?

Comment: There's is no a TM that halts for every $\langle p,x\rangle$. At first I thought that $L = \emptyset$ but, consider a TM that always returns TRUE. Isn't this  TM in $L$?

Comment: @Elimination does a TM that always returns TRUE decide the halting problem?

Comment: A TM in L needs to decide the halting problem, not just decide something. Thus, a TM that always returns TRUE is not in L, and you're right - $L=\emptyset$.

Comment: @RanG., it sure does as far as I can tell - it always halts, therefore it decides every input $\langle P,x \rangle$..

Comment: Oh I see your point @Shaull.

Comment: This phrase (in $L$'s definition) can be interpreted in two ways...

Comment: I read it in only a single way: M must be a decider for the language HP. But there are no such deciders, thus L is empty. What is the second interpretation on your mind?

Comment: Why are there so many of these questions here? It's like every CS student is studying languages, automata and machines.

Comment: And also: this is a trick question.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Well, it is always interesting to know a set of TM that are all painted green and can fly. Maybe you should look at other questions than those you choose.

Comment: I am just wandering why we get so many questions about languages and their classification. It's not like this is a very sexy topic – is it a standard topic in CS majors at US universities?

Comment: Semantic Capulets against computability Montague. An old story. Everything you want to know about Computer Science is in Romeo and Juliet. :) - - - We just get what the students get, for a good part.  And students do get a lot of unpalatable stuff.

Comment: @AndrejBauer. It is indeed a standard topic in many US universities, though I know from experience that many students find it tough going. (Actually, many students find most topics tough going. That's as it should be.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comments summary:

The language $L$ is decidable.

Hint:

> $L$ is in fact empty! It contains all the machines that decide the halting problem. But, the halting problem is undecidable => there are no machines that decide it.

Comment: Which responds to @Andrej's comment to the OP. Nice.